# Social login using scribe oAuth in ios

Tags: ios, scribe

I am going to implement social login's to my application is there any possible to get all login details from single library like scribe in iOS, Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few libraries you can use to get started with OAuth implementation on iOS:

1. **AFOAuth2Manager** https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Manager
2. **gtm-oauth** https://github.com/google/gtm-oauth for OAuth 1.0a
3. **gtm-oauth2** for OAuth 2.0
4. **OAuth2Client**

*There are other libraries which I'm not quite familiar with and could be better than the list above.*